# NullPointerException when passing from non empty Iterable to Array

Tags: scala

I fall on NullPointerException when i'm trying to convert an `Iterable` into an `Array` knowing that this one is filled with data.

Code will speak more concisely than i can.

In my case the generic type `A` is an `Array[Double]`

```scala
def ex1[A](it: Iterable[A])(implicit ct: ClassTag[A]): Array[A] = {
  // Check if each element is defined
  it.forall(Option(_).isDefined) // return true
  // Problem is comming
  it.toArray(ct) // NullPointerException
}

def ex2[A](it: Iterable[A])(implicit ct: ClassTag[A]): Array[A] = {
  Array[A](it.toSeq:_*)(ct) // NullPointerException
}
```

This `Iterable` is the result of a `groupBy` where i convert the `Array[A]` to `Iterable[A]` like this

```scala
def ex3[A : ClassTag](ar: Array[A]): Map[Int, Iterable[A]] = {
  ar.map((Random.nextInt(2), _)).groupBy(_._1).map{ case (k, values) => (k, values.map(_._2).toIterable) }
```

The scala version is 2.12.10.

Here is the stackTrace

```
[error] (run-main-6) java.lang.NullPointerException
[error] java.lang.NullPointerException
[error]     at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:290)
[error]     at scala.collection.TraversableOnce.toArray$(TraversableOnce.scala:288)
[error]     at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.toArray(Traversable.scala:108)
[error]     at xxx.yyy.problem where i'm doing the `toArray`
[error]     at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:238)
[error]     at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:36)
[error]     at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach$(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
[error]     at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:198)
[error]     at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:238)
[error]     at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:231)
[error]     at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:198)
```

The `TraversableOnce` file indicate the line of the `Array` creation as follow :

```scala
  def toArray[B >: A : ClassTag]: Array[B] = {
    if (isTraversableAgain) {
      val result = new Array[B](size) // TraversableOnce.scala:290
      copyToArray(result, 0)
      result
    }
    else toBuffer.toArray
  }
```

The problem comes when i'm calling toArray into the `Iterable[V]` from an `Array[K, Iterable[V]]`. It is generate as follow :

```scala
def groupByKey[K : ClassTag, V : ClassTag](arr: Array[(K, V)]): Array[(K, Iterable[V])] = {
    arr.groupBy(_._1).toArray.map{ case (k, agg) =>
      val works: Iterable[V] = agg.toIterable.map(_._2)
      val notWorks: Array[V] = agg.map(_._2)
      val notWorksToo: Array[V] = works.toArray
      val it = works
      (k, it)
    }
  }
```

Here is the stackTrace for the `notWorks` line

```
[error] java.lang.NullPointerException
[error]         at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuilder$.make(ArrayBuilder.scala:40)
[error]         at scala.Array$$anon$2.apply(Array.scala:66)
[error]         at scala.Array$$anon$2.apply(Array.scala:65)
[error]     at scala.collection.TraversableLike.builder$1(TraversableLike.scala:233)
[error]     at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:237)
[error]     at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:231)
[error]     at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:198)
[error]     at xxx.yyy.problem at notWorks line
[error]     at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:238)
[error]     at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:36)
[error]     at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foreach$(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
[error]     at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:198)
[error]     at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:238)
[error]     at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:231)
[error]     at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:198)
```

Comment: Can you provide full stacktrace of exception?

Comment: This snippet of code is unlikely to generate any NullPointerException. I cannot reproduce it. Please provide full exception stacktrace, and the call site code.

Comment: Do you happen to have a `null` `ClassTag` in the implicit scope by mistake?

Comment: Yes it is null, but i don't understand why. The classTag is supposed well defined in the final object on which i'm calling faling method, it implements a trait where the `implicit val ct: ClassTag[V]` is defined : 
`override implicit val ct: ClassTag[Array[Double]]  = classTag[Array[Double]]`. But for a reason i'm curious in, when i remove the implicit keywords it works :
`override  val ct: ClassTag[Array[Double]]  = classTag[Array[Double]]`

Comment: Your decision to use `imlicit ClassTag` parameter looks strange. Maybe you need to concentrate on main problem. What are you want to do? Convert generic `Array` to `Iterable` back and forth? Please, tell little more about your goal here!

Comment: If your A type is an Array, are you trying to create an Array[Array[Double]] from Array?